# Good freeware application to convert to VOB file to MPEG freeware

Tags: conversion, mpeg, vob

Does anyone know of a good freeware application where I can convert a full VOB file into a MPEG file.  All of the applications I have found are trial versions and will only convert a part of the video.

I just need to convert one VOB, do not plan on using it long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one here can convert VOB files to MPEG. It's free and works on XP, Vista and Windows 7.

[Koyote Video Converter](http://koyote-free-video-converter.softonic.fr/)

> **Supported format by Koyote Free Video Converter:**
>
> > **Import:** AVI, DIVX, MOV, MP4, FLV, 3GP, WMV, ASF, MKV, VOB, MPEG, MPG, M1V
> >
> > **Export:** 3G2, 3GP, ASF, MP3, AVI, DVD, FLV, MP4 (iPod, iPhone, PSP, Zune), MPEG1, MPEG2, WMV

Comment: This software worked the best.  Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Anytime buddy!!

Answer (score 2):

VOB files are already in mpeg format as described [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOB). You can just rename them to .mpg. You might need to set windows to "show file extensions for known file types". If you copied this file from a DVD that used some sort of encryption (most DVD's do) you will first have to decrypt the DVD using tools described on doom9.org.

Comment: This is not entirely true, and simply renaming VOB files to MPG is not recommended practice. While many programs accepting MPG will be able to read the files, the VOB-specific data can lead to undefined behaviour. I've had this first-hand very recently, where working with MPEG-PS editing software directly on VOB files lead to synchronisation issues, which disappeared once the streams were remuxed into an MPEG file.

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) used to be the de facto standard for converting video files.  It still does an admirable job.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) can fit your needs.

Here's a recent how-to to convert your .VOB file to AVI (remember that AVI is just a container) : [Avidemux VOB to AVI](http://silverwav.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/avidemux-vob-to-avi-lightning-fast/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [VOB2MPG](http://www.svcd2dvd.com/VOB2MPG/default.aspx). There is also a Pro version with additional features, but for simply converting (or rather, remultiplexing) VOBs to MPG files, the free edition is enough.