# Playing HD video on tablet

Tags: hdvideo, avchd

I have a HD video file with the following specs.

Format

```
Format                           : Matroska
File size                        : 19.6 GiB
Duration                         : 2h 41mn
Overall bit rate                 : 17.3 Mbps
```

Video

```
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames        : 4 frames
Muxing mode                      : Container profile=Unknown@4.1
Codec ID                         : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                         : 2h 41mn
Bit rate                         : 15.5 Mbps
Width                            : 1 920 pixels
Height                           : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 16:9
Frame rate                       : 23.976 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.311
Stream size                      : 17.5 GiB (89%)
Title                            : x264 - crf encode @ 55% of the original bitrate
Encoding settings                : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=10 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=64 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=5 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=2 / wpredb=1 / wpredp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=19.0 / qcomp=0.80 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=38000 / vbv_bufsize=30000 / crf-max=0.0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=1:1.00 / nal_hrd=none
```

The video doesn't play well in a machine with dual-core mobile CPU AMD Turion X2 TL-58 and NVIDIA Geforce 6150 Go. The CPU is 100% and there are framedrops. Is there a way to play this smoothly  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can play on Netbooks, provided they use nVidia's ION(2) platform.

Core AVC requirements make it pretty clear:

> 1080p video at 24-30 frames per second
>
> CPU - 2.8 GHz or faster Intel Pentium
>   4 or equivalent AMD processor
>
> RAM - At least 1GB of RAM
>
> GPU - 256MB or greater video card
>
> OS - Windows 98, 2000, XP, Vista, 7
>
> GPU Requirements for NVIDIA CUDA:*
>
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260/280/290/295,
>   9800, 9600, 9500, 8800 GT, 8800 GTS
>   512, 8700, 8600, 8500, 8400, Tesla
>   S1070/C1060, Quadro FX 3700, Quadro FX
>   3600M, Quadro FX 1700/FX 570/ NVS
>   320M/FX 1600M/FX 570M/FX 370/NVS
>   290/NVS 140M/NVS 135M/FX 360M/NVS 130M
>   and higher.and higher.
>
> You will also need drivers 191.07 or higher from NVIDIA.

So for your netbook, there's no way to play it smoothly, you probably will have to re-encode the file to a lower resolution to 720p (1280x720) perhaps.

Comment: what do i use to transcode from 1080p to 720p so that it can play on my netbook:Acer Aspire One AOA 150 and also the Hp tablet?

Comment: You can use a software like SUPER or Koyote. Have a look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/156799/good-freeware-application-to-convert-to-vob-file-to-mpeg-freeware